# Limit API request in a list

Tags: swift, rest

I have an app where I make an API call that allows me to fetch the currencies from the website. It represents all the currencies, however I need to limit them only to 3 "USD", "KZT", "AED", "RUB".

My code for fetching is below:

```
import SwiftUI

class FetchData: ObservableObject {

@Published var coversionData: [Currency] = []
@Published var baseCode = "USD"

 init() {
        fetch()
    }
    
func fetch() {
    
    let url = "https://open.exchangerate-api.com/v6/latest?base=\(baseCode)"
    
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, _, _ in
        
        guard let JSONData = data else {return}
        
        do {
            let conversion = try JSONDecoder().decode(Conversion.self, from: JSONData)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.coversionData = conversion.rates.compactMap({ (key,value) -> Currency? in
                    return Currency(currencyName: key, currencyValue: value)
                })
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    .resume()
}

func updateData(baseCode: String) {
    
    self.baseCode = baseCode
    
    self.coversionData.removeAll()
    fetch()
    
}
}
```

Can somebody share with my documentation, tutorial, GitHub link anything I just need to understand how to show only three categories?

Or example, please!

Comment: Can't you just call another endpoint on the api for each currency you want and store them after that in an array ? 
Or like after your call here filter ther results to keep only the currencies you want ? 
I don't get what is your problem here

Comment: Always start with the documentation https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs/pair-conversion-requests

Comment: @AdrienRoux Thank you so much for your reply, I am new to Coding and API's :) hopefully one day will help like you to other people!

Comment: @loremipsum thank you so much for your help I will definitely go through it.

Comment: @NursultanYelemessov No problem ! Didn't know you were new I hope you'll find you way through APIs :) 
Happy to help a bit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     //Properties
     @Published var filteredCurrency = "KZT"


 //.Filter call
.filter({ Currency in
                        Currency.currencyName == self.filteredCurrency
                    })
```

That was an answer because i believe I called a .filter and settled that Currency.currency name will be equal to a property which I gave it

now my code looks like this

```
    import SwiftUI

class FetchData: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var coversionData: [Currency] = []
    @Published var baseCode = "USD"
    @Published var filteredCurrency = "KZT"
    
init() {
    fetch()
}

func fetch() {
    
    let url = "https://open.exchangerate-api.com/v6/latest?base=\(baseCode)"
    
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, _, _ in
        
        guard let JSONData = data else {return}
        
        do {
            let conversion = try JSONDecoder().decode(Conversion.self, from: JSONData)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.coversionData = conversion.rates.compactMap({ (key,value) -> Currency? in
                    return Currency(currencyName: key, currencyValue: value)
                })
                .filter({ Currency in
                    Currency.currencyName == self.filteredCurrency
                })
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    .resume()
}

func updateData(baseCode: String) {
    
    self.baseCode = baseCode
    


       self.coversionData.removeAll()
        fetch()
        
    }
    
}
```